# Curl returns nothing with a function, but returns json object in terminal. How to debug?

Tags: php, json, curl

This is the URL that I am trying to get content from:

```
$url = 'http://mgcash.com/api/?a=get_offers&key=13658244dad4cfb3&country=US&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20%28Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.10;%20rv:35.0%29%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/35.0&format=json';
```

So I tried `file_get_contents()` and that one is working fine. Then I tried this function that always worked, but not in this case.

```
class SimpleCurl 
{

    public static function get($url, $params=array()) 
    {
        $url = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params, '', '&');
        $ch = curl_init();

        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 10,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false
        ];
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Then I tried using terminal with following command:

```
curl -X GET "http://mgcash.com/api/?a=get_offers&key=13658244dad4cfb3&country=US&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20%28Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.10;%20rv:35.0%29%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/35.0&format=json"
```

And that worked. It returned correct JSON object, without any problems.
Can anyone please let me know how do you debug CURL and figure what is the problem here?

After further tests and debugging I noticed following. Since my project require JSON object I am passing that fetched CURL `$content` trough `$json_data = json_decode($content);` and it returns nothing. Blank!

But if I try to `echo` or `print_r` before it goes trough `json_decode()`, I am literraly getting some RAW information/text and not JSON object. What the...

Comment: How do you call your `get` function (i.e. which arguments you provide)? I can look into it and add a solution for your particular case to my answer.

Comment: What does an `echo $url;` show?

Comment: `$content = SimpleCurl::get($this->credentials['NETWORK_URL']);`

Where `$this->credentials['NETWORK'URL']` = to the `$url` variable from above.

Comment: @dvLden again. We already saw the URL below. I asked what does `echo $url;` show inside that method. Maybe it's malformed. Also, I'm almost sure that `RETURNTRANSFER` should be `1` instead of `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing `$params` to the `get` function and your `$url` ends up like http://mgcash.com/api/?a=get_offers&key=13658244dad4cfb3&country=US&ua=Mozilla/5.0%20%28Macintosh;%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010.10;%20rv:35.0%29%20Gecko/20100101%20Firefox/35.0&format=json? note the appended `?`

You can change the `get` function to only concatenate the query string when `$params` is not empty, something like this:

```
...
if (!empty($params)){     
   $url = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params, '', '&');
}
```

Comment: Not passing params. URL is generated and ready for curl execution.

Comment: Yes, but you realize that you're appending an extra `?` to `$url` inside the function?

Comment: God damn it! I did not notice that! Well thank you, this resolves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` to output debug information:

> **CURLOPT_VERBOSE** - TRUE to output verbose information. Writes output to STDERR, or the file specified using CURLOPT_STDERR.

Though if you're running your script in a browser, you wouldn't see the verbose log, because by default it outputs all info to `stderr` (usually that output can be seen in your `error.log`).

So to see the logged info you should either look into your `error.log`, run your script in a terminal, or provide another file handler for cURL to output the log. In the most simple case you can just redirect the output to `stdout` as follows:

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR => fopen('php://stdout', 'w'),
    ...
];
```

In this case you'd see your log in your browser. Or, alternatively, you can provide any other filename to `fopen` to output the log in a file.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: I did not get any information by setting it within array of options within function.

Comment: @dvLden, I believe that you should also provide a `CURLOPT_STDERR` file handler if you run your script in a browser. You don't get any info because it's outputting to stderr (which can't be seen in a browser). I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: @dvLden I've updated my answer - now hopefully you'll be able to debug your cURL requests better! :)

Comment: Um what is suppoused to happen now. Will it output anything if everything is correct or I should make an problem now on purpose to see it in a browser?

Comment: @dvLden, no, it'll just provide "empirical" data by outputting your HTTP requests and responses (no matter if correct or incorrect). But if there's a problem you can immediately see where it is. You can get the same results by providing `-v` flag to `curl` in the console - e.g., try `curl -v https://google.com`, you'll see what I mean.